# Calculating probability in Java without the use of array lists?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, logic

The goal is to approximate the probability of throwing two die to get a specific combination of die totals. I would be able to do this through empirical testing methods, (collecting real data...) meaning, I would have to run a simulation that throws the two die and records how many times the number actually comes up. To be able to get a reasonable approximation of the real probability I would need to throw the die many, many times. (In this instance it is 20,000 times)

1. My program will also need to ask the user what die total is that they wish to test for and then generate and count the results from the 20,000 die throws mentioned earlier. To help the user see how the probabilities are converging I will need to print the running probability after each 1000 throws.
2. In terms of formatting, I must show the number of dice throws allowing for 6 digits, as well as show the probability results with 5 digits of accuracy after the decimal point.
3. Finally, the assignment explicitly states that I shouldn't code the output display with "if" statements, because I need to be able to change the number of die throws and get the correct display without changing the code.

**Example Run:**

```
Probability Testing Program

What die total do you wish to test for (2-12): 7

Computed probability for die throw = 7

Die throws     Probability
      1000     0.16000 
      2000     0.16950 
      3000     0.16467 
      4000     0.16850 
     ...
     18000     0.16611 
     19000     0.16695 
     20000     0.16685
```

**The code I wrote to reproduce the solution is as follows:**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * SRN: 507-147-9
 */
public class Lab7Part2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // new input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Define vars
        int rolls = 1, dice1, dice2, total, sum;
        long landmark;
        double probability = 0;

        // Name of program
        System.out.println("Probability Testing Program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What die total do you wish to test for (2-12): "); // prompt total dice rolls
        total = input.nextInt(); // store input as "total"
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Computed probability for die throw = " + total);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Die throws     Probability");

        landmark = 1000;

        while ((rolls <= 20000) && (landmark <= 20000)) {

            //Roll 2 random dice
            Random d1 = new Random();
            dice1 = 1 + d1.nextInt(6); // dice1 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 6);
            dice2 = 1 + d1.nextInt(6); // dice2 = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * 6);

            // The sum of the 2 dice rolls
            sum = dice1 + dice2;

            if (sum == total) {

                // calculating probability goes here??
                // probability = (math equation) ;
            }

            if (rolls == landmark) {
                System.out.printf("     %5d     %6.5f \n", landmark, probability);
                landmark = landmark + 1000;
            }

            rolls++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that I've encountered, is that I am unable to come up with a method of representing a probability formula which works for me inside my code. Therefore, even though I have no syntax or runtime errors, I am unable to produce a result which comes even remotely close to the probability column in the "Example Run" above. Unfortunately, unlike some of my classmates, I am not in a statistics class this semester, and therefore lack an "*introduction to combinatorics and probability*" which admittedly, would be quite useful in this instance!

For this specific course we haven't learned how to use arrays or array lists yet, and therefore is the reason for which I haven't included them in my code. I have, however, found a [Binomial Probability Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdoID.gif) online, to which I am curious if and how I would be able to incorporate it (with my respective variables in place of the ones referenced within the formula).

If any of the answers reach beyond basic programming concepts, can the answerer please explain how to tie it into a basic concept, or even provide a link to a resource to help explain it? For example, explaining that the `java.util.Random` class is a more convenient way of representing the basic `(int)(Math.random() * x)`. It would really help with my understanding!

Comment: You don't need complex formulas because you have the data. Just remember that you can't use integer division. You should you doubles for your floating point needs.

Comment: You can easily use arrays rather than ArrayList's because you know the number of trials. ``int[] rolls = new int[20_000];``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks about your code:

The declaration of your random variable should be done outside the loop. Whenever you use the new operator in java, you create an object. Since the loop is run several times (in your case 20000 times), you also create 20000 objects which is not useful. But if you do it before the loop, only one object is created, which you can use again and again.

For this task you do not need deeper knowledge of statistics. For the task you only need methods from the descriptive statistic and not from inferential statistic. You should calculate the impirical probability which is calculated simply by dividing `favourable events / all events`. For this you only need a counter to remember how often the randomly thrown numbers corresponded to the desired sum. For this purpose it would also be easier to use a for loop instead of a while loop.

You can use `DecimalFormatter` and display your probabilities with the desired decimal places.

I have modified your code with my remarks and suggestions and removed some unnecessary variables.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab7Part2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // new input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Define vars
        int dice1, dice2, total;
        long landmark = 1_000;;
        double probability = 0;
        int trials = 40_000;
        int countOfTotal = 0;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");

        // Name of program
        System.out.println("Probability Testing Program");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("What die total do you wish to test for (2-12): "); // prompt total dice rolls
        total = input.nextInt(); // store input as "total"
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Computed probability for die throw = " + total);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Die throws     Probability");

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 1; i <= trials; i++) {
            dice1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
            dice2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(6);
            if (dice1 + dice2 == total) {
                countOfTotal++;
            }
            if (i % landmark == 0) {
                probability = (double) countOfTotal / i;
                System.out.printf("     %5d     %-6s \n", i, df.format(probability));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `trials`, not `trails`.